# How to execute jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=?', function(data){
if (data.length > 0) {
    var link = jQuery('<a>').attr('http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id)
                            .text('Read');
});
```

I am just not exactly sure how to execute this on my website -- using javascript if possible. Can anyone give me a helping hand?

EDIT:

I'm not having any luck getting the text 'Read' to show up...at all. I am not too skilled at jQuery on a whole. I've only begun to use it. I do have jQuery in the head of my page.

Comment: What you mean, execute this? Unless you're loading the script from twitter, you won't be able to run it at all, due to cross-domain restrictions. Scripts from site 'a' (your site) cannot talk directly to site 'b' (twitter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code snippet somewhere on the page(I assume the jquery.js is already included some where on the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/brianj_smith.json?count=1&callback=?', function(data){ 
            if (data.length > 0) {     
                var link = jQuery('<a>').attr('href', 'http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id)                             .text('Read'); 
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery *is* written with JavaScript. Add a reference to jQuery using a script tag. Also place this in a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you don't know what jQuery is because it is already JavaScript. It's a library to do things more easy than with plain JavaScript. [Some documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)

To summarize what you are missing is:

- include the jquery JavaScript file
- put your code in a `<script></script>` element (and in `$(document).ready(function(){})`)
- have 1 or multiple `<a>` elements on your page

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to navigate to the link that you populate using your getJSON callback, then you can do something like this:

```
if (data.length > 0) {
    var link = 'http://twitter.com/brianj_smith/status/' + data[0].id;
    window.location.replace(link);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stick this inside `<script>` tags in your `<head>`, or at the end of `<body>` If you put it in the head, make sure you enclose it with `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`. Otherwise it will execute before the rest of the page is loaded.

And if you haven't already, you need to include jQuery in the head: `<script src='path/to/jQuery' type='javascript'></script>`